# Flutter - MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
```

I am getting this error when my app is in a background/Terminated state.

I am using SharedPreference Instance with firebase messaging, and in handling background messages, I got this exception.

**Solutions Tried:**

- changing build types
- changing proguard-rules.pro
- Changing MainActibity.kt file

by following this ->

- [Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for)

Nothing worked

Comment: This error is too damn common and there's no exact working solution for this, maybe because Devs are yet to figure why it happens, it's all hit and miss. The most common working solutions are either to turn off `minify` and `shrinkResources` in `build.gradle` or create a new Flutter project and paste all your code in that.

Comment: Tried it but had no luck, need to know why this is hapenning.

Comment: I'm in the same boat for now, searched StackOverflow and Github, nothing worked. Even [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64170696/8244632) and [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64256831/8244632) don't help now.

Comment: Same issue here. Does anyone have any luck?